# RSpec + DatabaseCleaner help -- teardown happening prematurely

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, datamapper

I'm a little lost with RSpec having always stuck to xUnit-based testing frameworks, but I'm giving it a go.

The nested nature of the way specs are written is giving me some headaches with regards to where I'm supposed to do database setup/teardown though.

According the to [DatabaseCleaner](https://github.com/bmabey/database_cleaner) README:

```
Spec::Runner.configure do |config|

  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end

end
```

Now I can't use transactions, because I use them in my code, so I'm just sticking to truncation, but that should be neither here nor there.

I have this:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.mock_with :rspec

  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end
end
```

The problem here is that any fixtures I create in a `subject` or `let` block have already disappeared (from the database) when I try to use them in a following `describe` or `it` block.

For example (using Machinist to create the fixtures... but that shouldn't be relevant):

```
describe User do
  describe "finding with login credentials" do
    let(:user) { User.make(:username => "test", :password => "password") }
    subject { User.get_by_login_credentials!("test", "password") }
    it { should == user }
  end
end
```

I'm struggling with how I'm supposed to be nesting these `describe` and `subject` and other blocks, so maybe that's my problem, but basically this fails because when it tries to get the user from the database, it's already been removed due to the `after(:each)` hook being invoked, presumably after the `let`?

Comment: BTW, you should still be able to use transactions to clean the DB. In most databases, transactions can nest (MySQL being the notable exception here -- just another way it sucks).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're going to use `subject` and `let` together, you need to understand how/when they are invoked. In this case, `subject` is invoked before the `user` method generated by `let`. The problem is not that the object is removed from the db before `subject` is invoked, but that it is not even created at that point.

Your example would work if you use the `let!` method, which adds a `before` hook that implicitly invokes the `user` method before the example (and therefore before `subject` is invoked).

That said, I'd recommend you stop struggling and use simpler API's that RSpec already exposes:

```
describe User do
  it "finds a user with login credentials" do
    user = User.make(:username => "test", :password => "password")
    User.get_by_login_credentials!("test", "password").should eq(user)
  end
end
```

That seems much simpler to me.

Comment: Thanks, you're definitely right about my not understanding how/when these blocks are invoked.  I originally started out just treating the outer `describe` in your code above like it was a `Test::Unit::TestCase` subclass, and each `it` like it was a test method in an xUnit framework.  Then I started reading somebody else's specs, who was using `subject ... ` followed a series of `it ... should` blocks, which convinced me I was doing it wrong.  I think I need to bang my head against a wall for a while before it makes sense ;)

Comment: Just quickly, if I need a fixture that is shared by all tests inside a `describe` block, where is the best place to do that?  Just use a `before(:each)`?  All these other methods have thrown me off track!

Comment: Glad it's beginning to clear up for you. The original intent of `subject` was to support `shoulda` matchers in one liners like `it { should validate_presence_of(:some_attr) }`. It wasn't really intended to show up in specs. It _is_ documented, and is public, and available, but the more I see it in people's specs, the more I think it shouldn't be there for both aesthetic reasons and for the obvious confusion that ensues when trying to use it alongside `let` and `before` hooks.

Comment: The best place for a common fixture is in a `before(:each)` hook. It's simple, intention revealing, and it works :)

Comment: You should look at let! which automatically executes the given block as a before hook for each example.

Answer (score 3):

You wrote:

> The problem here is that any fixtures I create in a subject or let block have already disappeared (from the database) when I try to use them in a following describe or it block.

That's right, that's how it works. (And you're not using fixtures in the usual Rails sense, but factories -- just as well, since Rails fixtures suck.)

Every individual spec (that is, every `it` block) starts (or should start) from a pristine database. Otherwise your tests would leak state and lose atomicity. So you should create every record you need within the spec in which you need it (or, as David said, in a `before` block to cut down on repetition).

As for organizing your specs...do it any way that makes sense. Usually there will be an outer `describe` block for the whole class, with inner `describe` blocks for groups of related behavior or specs that need a common setup. Each `describe` context can have its own `before` and `after` blocks. These get nested as you would expect, so the order of execution is something like
outer `before`
inner `before`
spec
inner `after`
outer `after`

If you'd like to see a project with a large number of RSpec specs and Cucumber stories (though for slightly old versions of each), check out http://github.com/marnen/quorum2 .

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, much appreciated.  Once I got going it all started to make sense.  Just some initial misunderstandings.  Using RSpec is a joy! (I actually started replying to this about 14 hours ago and I dunno what happened in that time ;) ... I think I switched tabs mid-typing).

Comment: Yeah, I like RSpec a lot. I find that its syntax encourages you to think about behavior, not implementation.